# Force emptying the trash on macOS from shell script

Tags: shell-script, macos

If I run this command in macOS (11.2.1) Terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

... after entering my Mac password in the system dialog, the trash is successfully forced empty.

But if I try to force empty the trash from this script file, the system dialog appears OK, and the notification works as expected, but the trash is not force emptied:

```
#!/bin/bash
if osascript -e "do shell script \"sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*\" with administrator privileges";
then
osascript -e "display notification \"Trash was forced empty.\" with title \"OK\""
else
osascript -e "display notification \"Trash was NOT forced empty!\" with title \"ERROR\""
fi
```

What am I doing wrong?